# Add DIV background image programmatically

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following DIV layout:

```
<div id="div_img" runat="server">
</div>
```

I would like to add a background image to my DIV at runtime so I use the code below:

```
div_img.Style.Add("background-image", "url('" + "..\emp_pic\" & myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(29).ToString() + "')")
```

The image's filename is from the database. But that code isn't doing what I wanted.

Comment: Can you post rendered HTML? Is image path correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Use "/" instead of "\"**

```
div_img.Style.Add("background-image", "url('" + "../emp_pic/" & myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).ItemArray(29).ToString() + "')")
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#div_img
{
background-image:url('..\emp_pic\');
background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

Why don't you use a css page and use this code! Using a css page is the perfered way to style and is accepted by the HTML5 standards.

Comment: i want to change the image using vb.net